# How do CNAMES work with SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I work with a web application used by several business units in my organization. The application is accessed using a general URL `http://app/` but some of the units use a business friendly URL e.g. `http://bu1/`, `http://bu2/` etc.

The application is soon to be integrated with a portal that requires it to be configured to use SSL and I was advised to request a certificate using a fully qualified domain name so I went with `app.company.com`. The certificate has been installed on the server and users access it using `https://app.company.com/`.

However I would also like them to be able to use `https://app/` or `https://bu1/` or `http://bu1/` etc. I'm not clear on how to do this, I think I have the following options:

1. Should I have requested a certificate without using the fully qualified domain name, just the CNAME?
2. I keep coming across subject alternative names but they appear to relate to different domains and I'd rather the users didn't need to use a domain at all. 3. Shoud I be looking for a wildcard certificate instead? I think one of the posts on here says they are not recommended.
3. Do I need a certificate per domain?

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: have you looked into ssl using *.mycompany.com?

Comment: The problem is (as i understand ssl) that using a domain name in the ssl that doesn't match the domain name accessed by the user will cause the browser to render a security error. So either a wildcard (which is way more expensive) or multiple ssls. I could be wrong and if i am I hope someone corrects me.

Comment: You can have `http(noS)://bu1/whatever` redirect *at the HTTP level* (not CNAME or other DNS) to `https://app.example.com/asneeded` without a certificate valid for `bu1`. This does not secure against sslstrip-type attacks, but if it is done entirely within the organization's intranet that is often good enough.

Comment: Thanks all for your help and advice - apologies it has taken so long to respond. Apparently the issue I am having is that http://bu1/ was pointing to a NameHost of servername.company.com rather than app.company.com. I've requested that http://bu1/ be pointed at app.compay.com and will advise if that works.

Answer (score 1):

SSL certificate providers will not hand out a certificate unless it lists a fully qualified domain name that you own through a registrar, so you will not be able to get a signed certificate for `https://app/` for instance.

What you need to do in this case, if you really want users to be able to access your app through `https://app/`, is to create your own self-signed SSL certificate, then insert the certificate into the browser's trusted certificate list on every computer in the company.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case you should set up a certification authority inside your company and issue certificates for the internal domains using your own CA. You'll have to make sure that the computers inside your company trust your root CA certificate automatically.

Also, you can't buy SSL certificates for an internal domain name/reserved IP address anymore.

From the [Baseline Requirements for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates, v.1.0](https://www.cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/Baseline_Requirements_V1.pdf)  (emphasis is mine):

> #### 9.2.1 Subject Alternative Name Extension
>
> **Certificate Field:**  extensions:subjectAltName
>
> **Required/Optional:**  Required
>
> **Contents:**  This extension MUST contain at least one entry.  Each entry MUST be either a dNSName containing the Fully-Qualified Domain Name or an iPAddress containing the IP address of a server.  The CA MUST confirm that the Applicant controls the Fully-Qualified Domain Name or IP address or has been granted the right to use it by the Domain Name Registrant or IP address assignee, as appropriate.
>
> Wildcard FQDNs are permitted.
>
> **As of the Effective Date of these Requirements, prior to the issuance of a Certificate with a subjectAlternativeName extension  or  Subject  commonName  field  containing  a Reserved IP  Address  or  Internal  Server  Name,  the  CA  SHALL notify the Applicant that the use of such Certificates has been deprecated by the CA / Browser Forum and that the practice will be eliminated by October 2016.**  Also as of the Effective Date, the CA SHALL NOT issue a certificate  with  an  Expiry  Date  later  than  1  November  2015  with  a  subjectAlternativeName  extension  or  Subject  commonName  field  containing  a  Reserved  IP  Address  or  Internal  Server  Name.    Effective  1  October  2016,  CAs  SHALL revoke all unexpired Certificates whose subjectAlternativeName extension or Subject commonName field contains a Reserved IP Address or Internal Server Name.  Address or Internal Server Name.